# Grouping data by timestamp date and time with linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to group some timestamps with folowing linq statement

```
        var ds = (from wl in dbEntities.tbl_weblog
                  group wl by new
                  {
                      wl.tms_stamp.Value.Date,
                      wl.tms_stamp.Value.TimeOfDay
                  } into dateGrp
                  select new
                  {
                      Date = dateGrp.Key.Date,
                      Time = dateGrp.Key.TimeOfDay,
                      HitCount = dateGrp.Count(),
                      TotalKB = dateGrp.Sum(m => m.int_bytes).Value / 1024
                  }
                      ).ToList();

        return Helpers.ToDataSet(ds);
```

But i'm getting error "**The specified type member '*Date*' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.**".

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq-To-Entities doesn't have a mapping for `DateTime.Date` to SQL.  So, instead you have to break it down into the Year, Month, Day, and Hour to get the results you are looking for.

```
var ds = (from wl in dbEntities.tbl_weblog
          group wl by new
             {
                 wl.tms_stamp.Value.Year,
                 wl.tms_stamp.Value.Month,
                 wl.tms_stamp.Value.Day,
                 wl.tms_stamp.Value.Hour
             } into dateGrp
          select new
          {
              Year = dateGrp.Year,
              Month= dateGrp.Month,
              Day= dateGrp.Day,
              Hour= dateGrp.Hour,
              HitCount = dateGrp.Count(),
              TotalKB = dateGrp.Sum(m => m.int_bytes).Value / 1024
          }).ToList();
```

Then when you consume `ds` you can put the date parts back together.

```
foreach(var item in ds)
{
    var date = new DateTime(item.Year, item.Month, item.Day);
    var hour = item.Hour;
}
```

Comment: ds is consumed in dataGridView in windows forms application and i need to show number of hits for each hour of each day. That's why i need to separate date and timeofday.

Comment: @onedevteam.com `TimeOfDay` wouldn't group this by hour.  You would have needed `DateTime.Hour` for that, and you need to break it down into Year, Month, and Day.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I actually did it this way before you updated answer, but i hoped that there is way to show date in one field instead 4... thanks anyway :)